# Fileupload Field Wicket error

Tags: java, file-upload, wicket-1.6

When I haven't fileupload tag(component), my code run fine. But when I add file input(component), when I submit, page only refresh, form is resseted, feedbackPanel don't show anything. I spent a day for  this error, but still  resolve it. Here is my code:

**AddProductPanel.java**

```
public class AddProductPanel extends Panel {
private FileUploadField imageUploadField;
private static final String UPLOAD_FOLDER = "/Users/luanvu/Data/";
private Product product;

public AddProductPanel(String id) {
    super(id);
    List<Categories> categoriesList = new CategoriesHome().listAll();
    product = new Product();
    final ProductHome productHome=new ProductHome();
    add(new FeedbackPanel("feedbackMessage"));
    Form<Product> form = new Form<Product>("addProductForm"){
        @Override
        protected void onSubmit() {
            super.onSubmit();
            File f=uploadFiel(imageUploadField.getFileUpload());
            if(f==null){
                error("Upload file fail");
                return;
            }
            product.setImg(f.getAbsolutePath());
            productHome.attachDirty(product);
            setResponsePage(ListProduct.class);
        }
    };
    form.setMultiPart(true);         
    form.setMaxSize(Bytes.kilobytes(100));
    form.add(new DropDownChoice<Categories>("category",
            new PropertyModel<Categories>(product, "categories"),
            categoriesList, new ChoiceRenderer<Categories>("name", "id")));
    form.add(new RequiredTextField<String>("name", new PropertyModel<String>(product, "name")));
    form.add(new RequiredTextField<Float>("price", new PropertyModel<Float>(product, "price")).add(RangeValidator.range(0.0f, null)));
    form.add(imageUploadField=new FileUploadField("imageUpload"));
    add(form);
}
private File uploadFiel(final FileUpload uploadedFile ){
    if (uploadedFile != null) {
    File newFile = new File(UPLOAD_FOLDER + uploadedFile.getClientFileName());
    if (newFile.exists()) {
        newFile.delete();
    }

    try {
        newFile.createNewFile();
        uploadedFile.writeTo(newFile);
        info("saved file: " + uploadedFile.getClientFileName());
        return newFile;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Error");
    }
    }
    return null;
}}
```

**AddProductPanel.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
 <wicket:panel>
  <div style="color: red" wicket:id="feedbackMessage"></div>
  <div style="margin: auto; width: 80%;">
   <form id="addProductForm" method="get" wicket:id="addProductForm">
    <fieldset id="add-product" class="center">
     <legend>Add Product</legend>
     <p>
      <span>Category</span> <select wicket:id="category">
      </select>
     </p>
     <p>
      <span>Name: </span><input type="text" id="name" wicket:id="name" />
     </p>
     <p>
      <span>Price: </span><input type="text" id="price"
       wicket:id="price" />
     </p>
     <p>
      <span>Image: </span><input type="file" wicket:id="imageUpload" />
     </p>
     <p>
      <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add" />
     </p>
    </fieldset>
   </form>
  </div>
 </wicket:panel>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There must be an error in your logs.
I'd bet the error is that the FileUploadField has `null` model and thus Wicket has no where to store the uploaded data.